# Paid iOS Application free to a particular user in Apple Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I have submitted a paid app to app store. The client needs to download the app from the store for free, but all the other users should download as a paid app.

I am not the in-app purchases. I am setting the Price Tier in iTunes.

Comment: I don't think this can be possible. Agreed with @Brian Shamblen.

Comment: Or simply give customer a promo code

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about a business concern related to the App Store, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate [Apple B2B](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) program for supplying apps to specific custiomers, this may suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

With Testflight Beta your client can download and install the app for 30 days. For a review this should be sufficient.

Otherwise I would use the promo code as well - if that is really required. I mean compared to the production cost this is less than peanuts ...